# python: How to plot and put annotation at a natural position

Tags: python, plot, annotations

I am using python to plot and my codes are:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# these are the data to be plot
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
x_test = ['grid50', 'grid100', 'grid150', 'grid250', 'grid500', 'grid750', 'NN5', 'NN10', 'NN15', 'NN20', 'NN50', 'NN100', 'CB', 'CBG']
clf = [0.58502, 0.60799, 0.60342, 0.59629, 0.56464, 0.53757, 0.62567, 0.63429, 0.63583, 0.63239, 0.63315, 0.63156, 0.60630, 0.52755]
hitrate = [0.80544, 0.89422, 0.94029, 0.98379, 0.99413, 0.99921, 0.99478, 0.99961, 0.99997, 0.99980, 0.99899, 0.99991, 0.88435, 1.0]
level = [23.04527, 9.90955, 4.35757, 1.46438, 0.51277, 0.15071, 1.30057, 0.00016, 0.00001, 0.00021, 0.00005, 0.00004, 6.38019, 0]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)

# this is the function to put annotation on bars
def autolabel(rects):
# attach some text labels
    for ii,rect in enumerate(rects):
        height = rect.get_height()
        plt. text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.02*height, '%s'% (clf[ii]),ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.xticks(x,x_test)

# this part is to plot the red bar charts
ins1 = ax.bar(x,clf,color='Red', align='center',label='classification results')
ax.set_ylabel('classification results', color='Red')
ax.tick_params(axis='y',colors='Red')
ax.set_ylim(0,1.5)
autolabel(ins1)

# this part is to plot the green hitrate and the for-loop is to put annotation next to the line
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ins2, = ax2.plot(x,hitrate,marker='o',color='Green', linewidth=3.0, label='hitrate')
ax2.set_ylabel('hitrate', color='Green')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y',colors='Green')
ax2.set_ylim(0,1.5)

for i,j in zip(x, hitrate):
    ax2.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j+0.02))


# this part is to plot the blue level, forloop same as that of hitrate
ax3 = ax.twinx()
axes = [ax, ax2, ax3]
ax3.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.1))
ax3.set_frame_on(True)
ax3.patch.set_visible(False)
ins3, = ax3.plot(x,level,marker='^', color='Blue', linewidth=3.0, label='obfuscation level')
ax3.set_ylabel('obfuscation level', color='Blue')
ax3.tick_params(axis='y',colors='Blue')
ax3.set_ylim(0,25)

for i,j in zip(x, level):
    ax3.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j+0.02))

ax.set_xlabel('Cell Configurations')
ax.set_xlim(0,15)
ax.set_title('benchmark')

ax.legend([ins1,ins2,ins3],['clf', 'hit', 'level'])

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

And I got a figure like :

[image]

The problem is that, some numbers are not put in a good place so to be read clearly, but I don't know whether there is a method to put the annotation naturally at a blank area. Any ideas?